# What is the syntax for MVC Controller method to return @Html.ActionLink in HTML couch?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, razor-2

Maybe a duplicate, but can't figure how to write a method in an MVC View .cs file callable to return the equivalent of @Html.ActionLink in a cshtml file.

Kind of like:

```
public string BrowseMenu
{
    return "<div><p>" + Html.ActionLink(" linktext ", "Action", "Controller") + "</p></div>";
}
```

What I want to do is return the same HTML structure with some ActionLinks in it to a bunch of different View pages in an MVC Controller, so if I am going about it the entire wrong way, that's where I am trying to get to.

Comment: note the remarks section of the msdn HtmlHelper class page [system.web.mvc.htmlhelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.108).aspx) mentions that HtmlHelpers are not appropriate for use in [MVC] Controllers or Models, which should just make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return an `ActionResult` from your controller to view, if you want to render some html. Otherwise, view will receive a string and display it as it is.

You can define a partial view which holds the html, and you can render this partial view in your main view.

```
public PartialViewResult MyActionLink()
{
    return PartialView("_MyPartialView");
}
```

`_MyPartialView` is just a view file holding the html you want to render.

---

However, I would suggest writing a custom html helper which I believe cleaner solution.

```
public static string MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<div><p>"); 
    sb.Append(helper.ActionLink("Text","Action","Controller"));
    sb.Append("</p></div>")
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Then you can render this custom html helper in your view via

```
@Html.MyActionLink()
```

Comment: the custom html helper you suggest is definitely better than what I have been trying, can't get where to code the method for accessibility from the MVC view though

Comment: Just create a new class and add this method to there. You can find an example here. http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/

Comment: VS2012 magic!  Not sure what I didn't have exactly right, probably the class name or namespace.  Thanks a bunch!